# Find console window size

Tags: c++

Freshman csci student. Have a program that requires knowing window size and I came across the following code that seems to work well:

```cpp
struct winsize w;     
ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);      
     
cout << w.ws_row << " " << w.ws_col << endl;
```

Would love if anyonw could explain how any of this works.

Comment: Reading "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" might give a good start.

Comment: It is a system function. Type `man ioctl_tty` at your terminal, or `ioctl tiocgwinsz` at [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ioctl+tiocgwinsz).

Answer (score 1):

Reading this: [ioctl manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) might help here.
`ioctl()` communicates information between the operating system and your application.
In your example, your output window ("console") has the internal name `STDOUT_FILENO` and with `TIOCGWINSZ` you kindly ask for window size information to be put into the variable `w`.
That's it.